# How to add configuration in .NET 6 Program.cs only?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0, .net-6.0

On an AspNetCore 5 Web and API Projects I had the following on Program files:

```
  public class Program {

    private static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .AddJsonFile("settings.json", false, true)
      .AddJsonFile($"settings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", false, true)
      .AddEnvironmentVariables()
      .Build();

    public static Int32 Main(String[] args) {

      CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(String[] args) {

      IHostBuilder builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
        
      builder
        .UseSerilog()
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder => {
          builder
            .UseConfiguration(Configuration)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
        });

      return builder;  
      
    }
  
  }
```

Now I am moving this code to NET 6 using `Program.cs` without `Startup.cs`:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

builder.Configuration
  .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
  .AddJsonFile("settings.json", false, true)
  .AddJsonFile($"settings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", false, true)
  .AddEnvironmentVariables();

builder.Host.UseSerilog();

builder.Host.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(x => { 
  x.UseSerilog(); / ??
  x.UseConfiguration(??); // ??
  x.UseWebRoot("webroot"); 
});

await using WebApplication application = builder.Build();
```

**Question**

1. Can I set configuration in `builder.Configuration` or should I do it inside ConfigureWebHostDefaults?
2. Should I use `builder.Host.UserSerilog` or add Serilog in `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`?

It's a bit confusing because I can do things in different ways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [new hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#new-hosting-model) uses `WebApplicationBuilder` to configure the web-host defaults, so there's no need for you to call this yourself.

> Can I set configuration in `builder.Configuration` or should I do it inside `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`?

Do this using `builder.Configuration`.

> Should I use `builder.Host.UserSerilog` or add Serilog in `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`?

Do this using `builder.Host`. Nicholas Blumhardt demonstrates this in [Setting up Serilog in .NET 6](https://blog.datalust.co/using-serilog-in-net-6/).

> It's a bit confusing because I can do things in different ways.

There's a strong need for backwards compatibility, especially as .NET 6 apps aren't required to use the new hosting model. This results in a few different approaches being available to you. I expect this is something that will change with future releases, but that's merely speculation on my part.

Answer (score 6):

*1. Can I set configuration in `builder.Configuration` or should I do it inside `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`?*

To manage configuration you should use `ConfigurationManager` exposed by `builder.Configuration`:

```cs
builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("settings.json", false, true)
    .AddJsonFile($"settings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", false, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

*2. Should I use `builder.Host.UserSerilog` or add `Serilog` in `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`*

From Nicholas Blumhardt's (one of the Serilog maintainers) [github sample](https://github.com/datalust/dotnet6-serilog-example) use `builder.Host`:

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => // Serilog setup here, use ctx.Configuration for config);
```