# How to handle deprecation of IWebHostBuilder.UseSerilog() when IWebHostBuilder is still needed?

Tags: serilog

The `UseSerilog()` extension is deprecated* for `IWebHostBuilder` in serilog-aspnetcore version 5.0.0. However, I'm still using a `IWebHostBuilder` and a `Startup` class (aspnetcore 6), and `IWebHostBuilder` is not deprecated.

Since deprecation implies future removal, how should I leverage Serilog going forward?

---

* Reference:
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/releases/tag/v5.0.0

> mark `IWebHostBuilder` extensions as obsolete on platforms with `IHostBuilder`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70366314/11635

Comment: Thanks @RubenBartelink. That post doesn't seem to address my question as I'm using IWebHostBuilder.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by switching to `IHostBuilder` instead of `IWebHostBuilder`. The key in my case was to call `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` (or `ConfigureWebHost`), where you can then utilize an `IWebHostBuilder`.

In this way, I could call `UseSerilog` on the `IHostBuilder` while still utilizing the `Startup` class as before with an `IWebHostBuilder`.

Example:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // temp initial logging
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .CreateBootstrapLogger();

    using var app =
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder
                => webHostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                        _ = config.SetBasePath(hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true))
                    .UseStartup<Startup>())
            .UseSerilog(
                (hostingContext, loggerConfig) =>
                    loggerConfig
                        .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
                        .Enrich.FromLogContext(),
                writeToProviders: true)
            .Build();
    app.Run();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I Solved with:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.UseSerilog();
```

Comment: I believe that assumes you're using the new minimal hosting model. As stated, I'm using IWebHostBuilder and a Startup class, so this isn't applicable.